# Why do we misnomer MariaDB as a "mysql-server"?

Tags: debian, mysql, mariadb

I've had an interesting discussion recently, about whether it is okay to call MariaDB a "mysql server" when in reality, Maria is not 100% compatible with MySQL.

I understand it was originally a 100% drop-in replacement fork of MySQL, but at the time of writing, MariaDB 10.5 and MySQL 8.0 are not 100% compatible with each other.

Why is it then that major distributions like Debian host packages like "default-mysql-server" that install MariaDB-server? Shouldn't the general, umbrella package be called "default-sql-server"?

Comment: This question is likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. It should be updated so it will lead to fact-based answers.

Comment: The use and administration of the available SQL server software is too diverse to call any of them "the default". MariaDB and MySQL are far more similar to each other than these two vs. PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Shouldn't the general, umbrella package be called "default-sql-server"?

Definitely not. MariaDB, MySQL are far from being the only or the "default" SQL server. There's important free software competition.

> but at the time of writing, MariaDB 10.5 and MySQL 8.0 are not 100% compatible with each other.

"Not 100% compatible" is not really a good reason. Your xserver package also is still called xserver, which contains xorg, which isn't 100% compatible with the original XFree86 that most distros shipped under that name.

MariaDB *is* an implementation of the mysql server. full stop. The libraries, clients and tooling for it still carry MySQL in their name.

The fact that the main project has now incompatible feature is mainly focused on the difference between Oracle's GPL ("community") version of the database and the commercial, non-free versions. (Most of the technical changes in the GPL version can directly be adopted by MariaDB – that's the point of the GPL.)

Since no free Linux distro can ship the commercial version anyways, it's logically consistent of them to assume that the continuation of the originally GPLv2-only DBMS under the name of MySQL is the dominant GPLv2-only fork, MariaDB.

Comment: The `xorg` example is useful in contrast to MariaDB: in Debian for example, there were transitional `xfree86` packages, but they were dropped in 2007. So it’s an example of a different way of handling this; it doesn’t support your argument... (The X server package in Debian is `xserver-xorg`, not `xserver`.)

Comment: I would imagine "default-sql-server" would be what ever the packager decides is "default", and in that sense, it could well be MariaDB or MySQL, or whatever. (Though how useful a package giving just some SQL server would be, that's a different question)

Comment: Thank you, this example sums it up pretty well. It makes sense to name it after the GPL version of Oracle's SQL server.

Comment: it's **not** the GPL version of Oracle's SQL Server! Oracle SQL is yet a completely different thing. MariaDB also *not* the "GPL version of Oracle's MySQL". Oracle's MySQL is just as much a continuation of the original MySQL (which was and is GPL-licensed) software project as MariaDB is.

Answer (score 0):

The main reason MariaDB has so many elements using the name "mysql" is implied on the MariaDB Foundation's web page titled "MariaDB in Brief", under the header "MariaDB Server" (URL: https://mariadb.org/en/#mariadb-server

Specifically:

> Until MariaDB 5.5, MariaDB Server followed the MySQL version numbering schema, aiming for drop-in compatibility with the same major version of MySQL.

and

> MariaDB Server still retains high levels of compatibility with MySQL, and most popular applications that use MySQL will work seamlessly with MariaDB.

and

> MariaDB Server has a strong emphasis on not breaking backwards compatibility for its users.

Synthesizing this together:

- MariaDB started as a drop-in replacement for MySQL, which required supporting the commands and scripts that had been written for MySQL.  (parallel example: MTAs like Postfix and Exim include a `sendmail` command to support commands/scripts created for Sendmail)
- Compatibility with MySQL is still a high priority, although today it's no longer at the level of "drop-in replacement".
- Renaming the parts of MariaDB that were originally named to be "drop-in" replacements for MySQL risks breaking backward compatibility with earlier versions of MariaDB, and the project tries to avoid this.